# Why is it said that the Heisenberg model is a hard-core boson model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

I am confused as to why it is said that the Heisenberg model is a hard-core boson model.

Comment: until you get a theorist's answer have a look at this search http://books.google.gr/books?id=utSV09ZuhOkC&pg=PA247&lpg=PA247&dq=Heisenberg+model+is+hard-core+boson+model&source=bl&ots=25cRLAXORC&sig=HTHXv4G9l2WmeWcm1a7Vh9dGYFc&hl=el&sa=X&ei=sXMvVNzvM431aOXwgPgH&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAw  . It seems that in this case the model ends up with a U(1) symmetry instead of SU(2)

Comment: Is your question asking what it means for a model to be described as a "hard core boson model", or are you asking why it is that the Heisenberg model in particular is included in the set of hard core boson models?

Comment: why is it that the Heisenberg model in particular is included in the set of hard core boson models

Comment: Well, the Heisenberg model is bosonic and when you write it down in the Holstein-Primakoff representation you find it to have the same interaction term as a low-temperature bose gas with a hard-core interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The two-particle interaction in the Hubbard model is non-zero only when these two particles occupy the same site, ie. get as close as it gets for the given band structure. This is similar to balls with hard cores - they only interact if the cores overlap.